# how do I print the variable value for my IA32 assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86, printf

I have been tasked to Create an IA32 assembly program of a simple for loop:

```
int main() {
    int data = 50;
    int b = 20;
    for (b=20; b<data; b=b+1) {
        printf(“value of b: %d\n”, b);
    }
return 0;
}
```

(task shown in link below)

[image: screenshot of my task to complete]

I have created a working for loop but do not know how to print out the value of `b` each time is is incremented by 1. this is my solution:

```
.section .data
msg
    .ascii "the value of b is: %d/n"
data:
    .int 50
b:
    .int 20

.section . text
.globl _start
_start:
    movl data, %ebx

loop1:
    incl b
    pushl b
    call printf
    pop b
    cmp b, %ebx
    jge loop1

    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

When i compile it in and run it in GDB i get the following message:
[image: Screenshot of GDB output]

Admittidly, i don't fully understand the `printf` command and would really appreciate the help.

Comment: I am not very much into assembler (only had a bit of MIPS in university) but aren't you missing to push the format string?

Comment: You also need to push the address of msg before the call to printf

Comment: @memo can you please elaborate on how i would do that?

Comment: You can use registers for both local variables: ESI, EDI, and EBP are call-preserved, like EBX, in the 32-bit calling convention you're using.  Also, you should `pop` into a dummy register like EAX or something, or just `add $4, %esp`, not pop back into `b`.  `printf` is allowed to modify its args on the stack.  (It probably doesn't, so your program would work if you did `push $msg` and changed the `/n` to `\n` in the string.

Comment: Anyway, what's your question?  Does another `next` not leave the printf@plt stub?  Use `finish` if needed.  Or use `nexti` instead of `next` to more reliably step over call instructions instead of into them, if that's the problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes i tried popping into `%eax` or adding `add $4, %esp` but still the same error remais. https://imgur.com/a/1jgg2wB that is a screenshot of what happens if i continue to do another `next`.

Comment: Those changes have nothing to do with how GDB behaves, just the correctness of your program.  Like I said, use `finish`, or use `layout asm` and `nexti` or `stepi` if you want to single-step inside `printf` instead of leaving it.  It sounds like `as` didn't make perfect debug info for asm source lines, probably because you left out the `-g`, but you're trying to use source-level GDB commands like `next` instead of `nexti`.